# Flutter Local Notifications :Targeting S+ (version 31+) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement the package : `flutter_local_notifications`.

I have updated `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.0'` to its latest version but the error keeps happening.
Here are my build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.6.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.5.0"
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.0'
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
-Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.

-Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles
```

How can i solve this problem?